# Prove that the intersection of pairwise disjoint sets is empty

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to show that $\displaystyle \bigcap_{i=1}^{n}A_i=\emptyset$ where $A_i\cap A_j=\emptyset \hspace{6pt} \forall i\ne j$.

I tried to show it by induction, but I got to a dead end.

How should I prove this claim? It seems trivial, but I couldn't find a legit proof.

Thank you!

Comment: This is wrong for $n=1$.

Comment: @Christoph, of course it is, the base case is n=2.

Comment: Assuming $n>1$, note that $\displaystyle \bigcap_{i=1}^{n}A_i\subseteq A_1 \cap A_2$.

Comment: @SolidSnake, thanks for this observation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i \subset A_i \cap A_j = \varnothing$ for all $i\ne j$.